# JPA 2.0 Hibernate 4.3/5.x java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-5.x

So I ran into the aforementioned `ClassNotFoundException`. Apparently in the newer versions of hibernate `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder` is dependent on `javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery`. This is correct behaviour if you are using JPA 2.1. However this is not the case when you need JPA 2.0.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add hibernate-entitymanager to your classpath. This is an empty jar but for some reason it makes the core jar jpa 2.0 compliant.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Since 5.2, `hibernate-entitymanager` simply redirects to `hibernate-core`.

Comment: You are correct but I found that if the entitymanager package is not on the classpath the core module will use the JPA 2.1 interface.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just ended-up using the 2.1 interface anyway, or it will still crash with the ClassNotFoundException. Anyway you shouldn't forcefully downgrade with that exclusion as you tried. That was the real problem.